# Raspberry Pi 2 lights stay solid while the chip is getting really hot

Tags: boot-issues

This only started to happen yesterday. The pi powers on but the LEDs stay solid while the chip near the USB ports on the top starts to get very warm. I've tried multiple SD cards with no avail, can someone help?

Comment: Does the Pi work?

Comment: This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker! (Read: it's most likely dead.)